# Image link not clickable

Tags: css, hyperlink, clickable, resizable

Hello i have been working on this website for a while and i have been working on making it resizable when you adjust the window size (or resolution of screen) and when i finally got it to work now the links on the graphics are not clickable

http://javiermedinaloera.com/

Here is my website, all of the circles are coded to be links but only two of them work

Thank you very much, i would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

I know what your problem is: you have 100% width for all items in each line, but they have the same z-index, of course one will "cover" the others. The solution is change the width of them, give each of them a width let's say 250px, then adjust your "left" attribute. Probably you could see your site works in IE, because IE doesn't render your css the ORDINARY way.

Comment: i have tried giving them different widths and adjusted the left attribute but the result was the same, here is the last modification:

Comment: #arrieros {width:80%; text-align: center; position: fixed; right: 400; left: -150px; top: 179px;   }
  #mediosiglo {width:70%; text-align: center; position: fixed; left: 200px; top: 179px;    }
   #reportajes {width:60%; text-align: center; position: fixed; left: 550px; top: 179px;  }
    #twitter {width:50%; text-align: center; position: fixed; left: 100px; top: 440px;  }
  #acercademi {width:40%; text-align: center; position: fixed; left: 400px; top: 440px;  }
   #facebook {width:30%; text-align: center; position: fixed; left: 700px; top: 440px;  }
 
 </style>

Comment: you should give them much smaller width. didn't you realize 80%+70%+60% is 210% ??? you'd better give them in pixel, as your image is 247px in width, you should give 247px, then adjust "left" again

Comment: I changed the circles for some squares and now there is no overlapping, it was indeed a problem with the width of all the elements, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your div tags are not formatted with specific widths. Each div tag is  taking up close to the whole width of the page. You need to give them specific widths. In the style tag at the top, add this CSS.

```
    <style type="text/css">#arrieros{ width: 270px; }</style>
```

Just set the width to 270px for each div that you have and it should work fine.

Comment: i tried modifying it with pixels instead of % but that way the circles don't adjust to the screen resolution or when the window size is modified

Comment: I fixed the width and changed the circles for some squares and now there is no overlapping and all of the links are clickable, thanks a lot!